# Prove the existence of regular $C$ so that: $A \prec C \prec B $

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

Given $A,B$ regular languages with $A \prec B$. Prove the existence of $C\in L_{\text{regular}}$ so that: $A \prec C \prec B$.

Here, $A\prec B$ stands for: $A\subset B $ and $B\setminus A $ is infinite.

I tried to go for: $C=\overline{B} \cup A$ and some other options but it didn't work out.

Comment: Study the answer to the recent question [How can i partition an infinite regular language into 2 strange infinite regular languages?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18610/how-can-i-partition-an-infinite-regular-language-into-2-strange-infinite-regular).

Comment: Where did the comments go? You cannot prove that $C$ exists without some conditions on $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You are right. The question was edited so that $A \prec B$ is also given, now it's correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Note that $B \setminus A$ is regular by closure properties of $\mathsf{REG}$.

> Since $B \setminus A$ is also infinite, you can [find an infinite language](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18610/how-can-i-partition-an-infinite-regular-language-into-2-strange-infinite-regular) $D \in \mathsf{REG}$ so that $D \prec B \setminus A$.

Comment: @DaniaG. I phrased my answer as a hint deliberately, so I'd appreciate it if you removed that spoiler for future visitors.